# Is it possible to create a rule that fails build if the new code coverage is less than the current code coverage

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage

Is there a way to have a dynamic code coverage threshold in sonarqube so that all new code coverage should be at or above the current code coverage?

I don't see an out-of-the-box solution, but not sure of any other alternatives.

Comment: Maybe you can use the SonarQube API? What have you investigated?

Comment: Actually,  as a hack I could use the api and a recurring task (eg, cron) to check and adjust the metric if the code coverage is higher than the current test metric.

Comment: If it is.NET code you can integrate NDepend into SonarQube https://www.ndepend.com/docs/sonarqube-integration-ndepend and then modify thresholds in this default rules (click "CQLInq Source Code" you'll see the threshold) https://www.ndepend.com/default-rules/NDepend-Rules-Explorer.html?ruleid=ND1601#!